# Can't sync SIP Address, can't query it in search even when added manually

Tags: 2013, search, javascript, ajax

## Issue 1

I'm trying to pull back a user's SIP address using the search service. I have this manually entered for the time being in a particular profile. My query:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + queryText + ":" + query + "*'&selectproperties='LastName,FirstName,JobTitle,WorkEmail,WorkPhone,Department,SipAddress'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&sortlist='LastName:ascending,FirstName:ascending'&rowlimit=500&startRow=" + startRow,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/xml",
        },
        success: function (xml) {
            onSuccess(xml, startRow);
        },
        error: onError
    });
```

And in my XML response, I find the profile (that I manually entered the SIP address for in the User Profile SA) and here's the SIP Address:

```
<d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
    <d:Key>SipAddress</d:Key>
    <d:Value m:null="true" />
    <d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType>
</d:element>
```

I have run a full crawl since adding this to the user's profile and verified its success... So for some reason the SIP address for this profile is coming back null. This is the only profile that has a SIP address entered for now, which leads me to issue 2.

## Issue 2

When I sync the User Profile SA with AD, none of my profiles get any SIP addresses sync'd in. For the same profile above, I have the user attribute `msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress` populated with a value, but it is not sync'd in to the User Profile Service.

Any ideas on either of these issues?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this configuration in my demo environment. After running a Full sync the SIP Address attribute was correctly imported to the User Profile. To troubleshoot you may need to look at the MIISClient logs to ensure that the attributes are being retrieved from AD correctly. In my case the initial value was coming from ProxyAddress and was not populated. This change updated it correctly.

Once you get the import working:

For the User Profile Property, you need to set it to Indexed.

For Search, you'll have to run a full crawl on the User Profiles. (sps3://)

I ran your query and the JSON result was this:

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.KeyValue"
  },
  "Key": "SipAddress",
  "Value": "sip:willa@doghousetoys.com",
  "ValueType": "Edm.String"
},
```

Comment: To clarify a bit here - you need to set the SIP address property to "Indexed" in the user profile service:  CA -> User Profile Service -> Manage User Properties -> SIP Address (edit) -> Search Settings -> Check the box for "Indexed"

Comment: Thanks Phil, but my answer states that already.